# Vulkan renderpasses - Using an attachment as a texture

Tags: vulkan

From the spec, under `VkFramebufferCreateInfo`:

> Image subresources used as attachments must not be used via any non-attachment usage for the duration of a render pass instance.

Does this mean using an attached image as a texture in a subsequent pass is not allowed?

This is confusing, since the application must update `subpassInput` descriptors manually, which seems to imply:

- it is the only descriptor that may be updated with an attached image during a renderpass instance
- or the real meaning of that passage is to restrict the scope to just "rendering" as opposed to resource transfer, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input attachments are *attachments*, and therefore using them is not a "non-attachment use". Just because they happen to also involve a descriptor does not mean that they're not still attachments.

> Does this mean using an attached image as a texture in a subsequent pass is not allowed?

If by "as a texture", you mean by binding it to a non-input attachment descriptor, then yes, that is not allowed in the same render pass instance where that image subresource is being used as an attachment.

Input attachments of course are not "textures"; they're attachments.